# Hadoop pig technology group by function

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

i have a relation A contains

```
(zip-code).
```

i have another relation B contains

```
(name:gender:zip-code)

(x:m:1234)

(y:f:1234)

(z:m:1245)

(s:f:1235).
```

i want to group the data in relation B by A

```
C = GROUP B BY A::zipcode;
```

expected output:

```
(1234,{(y,f,1234),(x,m,1234)})

(1235,{(s,f,1235)})

(1245,{(z,m,1245)})
```

Comment: [Read How to ask on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a query

Comment: You should also provide expected output.

Comment: I don't see the need of relation A, can you provide sample inputs for A and B and let us know your objective

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need of relation A. If objective is to group by zip code field which is already there in relation B then the below code is suffice.

```
C = GROUP B BY zip_code;

DUMP C; -- Will have the expected output.
```

Comment: thanku, but i dont wnat to use zip_code directly,,,i want that output using any variable or relation having zip_code

Comment: I m not clear of objective here, can you share sample input and expected output ?

Comment: please help me ....how to write pig script to group data by a field having 3 distinct values in a relation